# On how to learn Xiangqi (Chinese Chess) or Shogi (Japanese Chess)

Tags: learning, chess-variants, xiangqi, shogi

I learned international chess using the tutorials in Ubisoft's Chessmaster, alongside doing tactical and strategical exercises from books, studying master games, and from playing.

I want to learn how to play Xiangqi or Shogi. What resources would you recommend? I am particularly interested in software like Ubisoft's Chessmaster, i.e. interactive tutorials with the ability to play against a range of computer players at different levels.

P.S. I'm based in the UK, where there aren't any relevant clubs nearby, and English language resources are a must

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned shogi from this book. [http://www.amazon.com/Shogi-Beginners-John-Fairbairn/dp/4871872017/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446638715&sr=1-1&keywords=shogi+for+beginners](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4871872017)

snippet:  http://www.bromsgrove-abstract-games.org.uk/shogi.pdf

I bought a shogi set from The Shogi Association (A UK group). The fellow running it at the time (George Hodges) has since passed, I believe.

I also was fortunate to have a friend in Japan. He brought me back a Japanese language puzzle book. I don't recall the exact name, but they are mate-in-x puzzles where one must use all the pieces in hand.  Maybe they are called tsume puzzles? I saw the name referenced on that Amazon link.

It's a great game!

Comment: I have got that book as well, though I never progressed to a level were I could play a decent game. There is a certain shortage of books on shogi (or, I guess XiangQi), but this one is quite good.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster The best XiangQi books are in Chinese.

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant shogi/xiangqi books in English.

Answer (score 6):

I learned Shogi from [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/HIDETCHI).  It goes from absolute beginner to analysis of grand-master games.

Comment: I thought to myself "Is this HIDETCHI?" before clicking the link. I love that guy!

Answer (score 1):

Try below Ebook, all free for download.
http://xiangqielephantgame.blogspot.my/p/download-free-ebook.html?m=1

Comment: Welcome to Chess SE! From your username, this seems to be a link to your site. Can you please [edit](http://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/14923/edit) your answer to state this clearly? Otherwise, your post can be perceived as [spam](http://chess.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any english resources for learning xiangqi other than the webpage mentioned above. There is a Malaysian titled player who produced xiangqi content in English. The link for his video resources on xiangqi can be found here: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqkiX5bDGUQAzgBcz7V29KA)

There are a few xiangqi players on the pychess.org site's discord who are willing to help out in xiangqi studies and openings. But overall the game is less popular outside China.